# Ashikhmin-Shirley model implementation: ugly result

Tags: glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I am trying to implement the Ashikhmin-Shirley model using these formulas:

[image]

This is the GLSL 1.2 fragment shader code:

```
uniform vec4 materialAmbient, materialDiffuse, materialSpecular;
uniform float materialShininess;
uniform vec4 lightAmbient, lightDiffuse, lightSpecular, lightPosition;

varying vec3 P,N;


float pi= 3.1415926535;


vec4 Fd(float NdotV, float NdotL) {
    vec4 fd= (28.0 * materialDiffuse * lightDiffuse) / (23.0 * pi) * (1.0 - materialSpecular * lightSpecular);
    fd*= 1.0 - pow(1.0-NdotV/2.0,5.0);
    fd*= 1.0 - pow(1.0-NdotL/2.0, 5.0);
    return fd;
}

vec4 Fr(float u, vec4 specular) {
    return specular + (1.0-specular) * pow(1.0 - u, 5.0);
}

// f= phi
vec4 Fs(float VdotH, float NdotH, float NdotL, float NdotV, float et, float eb, float f) {
    vec4 fs= Fr(VdotH, materialSpecular * lightSpecular);
    fs*= sqrt((et+1.0) * (eb+1.0)) / (8.0 * pi);
    fs*=  pow(NdotH, et*pow(cos(f),2.0) + eb*pow(sin(f),2.0)) / (VdotH * max(NdotL, NdotV));
    return fs;
}


void main(void) {
    vec3 L= normalize(vec3(lightPosition) - P);
    vec3 V= cameraPosition;
    vec3 H= normalize(L+V);
    float NdotL= max(dot(N,L),0.0);
    float NdotV= max(dot(N,V),0.0);
    float NdotH= max(dot(N,H),0.0);
    float VdotH= max(dot(V,H),0.0);
    gl_FragColor= Fd(NdotV, NdotL) + Fs(VdotH, NdotH, NdotL, NdotV, 128.0,128.0,1.0);
}
```

I already checked and it seems like all the uniforms and varying are passed in the right way, I pass P and N from the vertex shader. The variables are:

1. Light direction: L;
2. Surface normal: N;
3. Camera direction: V;
4. Half vector: H;
5. Fragment position: P.

The uniforms I pass are:

1. light{Specular | Diffuse | Ambient} : 0xffffff (converted to a rgba vector of course);
2. materialAmbient: 0x543807 ;
3. materialDiffuse:  0xc6901d;
4. materialSpecular: 0xfdefce;
5. materialShininess: 27.8974.

This is the result I get:

[image]

Which seems very strange to me, I've seen other images of Ashkhmin-Shirley implementations on the web, and they aren't similar. This is an example:

[image]

I want one like this !! Maybe I am using wrong values of phi and other values? Or there's something wrong in the formula?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing braces here:

```
vec4 fd= (28.0 * materialDiffuse * lightDiffuse) / (23.0 * pi) * (1.0 - materialSpecular * lightSpecular);
```

try

```
vec4 fd= ((28.0 * materialDiffuse * lightDiffuse) / (23.0 * pi)) * (1.0 - materialSpecular * lightSpecular);
```

instead.